# cambiar orden con css

Tags: html, css, angular5

tengo el siguiente codigo html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'cambio': !orden, 'componente':orden}">
    <app-nombre [isEdit]="isEdit" [ngClass]="{'cambioNombre': !orden}"></app-nombre>
    <app-apellidos [orden]="orden" [isEdit]="isEdit" [ngClass]="{'cambioApellido': !orden}"></app-apellidos>
  </div>
```

Y tengo esto en el css:

```
.cambioApellido{
  order: 1;
}
.cambioNombre{
  order: 2;
}
```

Hay alguna forma de cambiar el orden de este div con css??

Comment: No me cambia el orden, sigue saliendo como en el html

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad `order` solamente está disponible para los elementos que sean **cajas flexibles** por lo que tendrás que decirle a su padre que tenga `display: flex;`

```css
.caja {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.caja .uno {
  order: 2;
}

.caja .dos {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <p class="uno">Elemento 1</p>
  <p class="dos">Elemento 2</p>
</div>
```

**Referencia:** [Cajas flexibles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)